# cshtml passing model to JS submit function?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a way I can pass the Model.SortOrder number to the JS submit function?

JS

```
  $("#pubmed-form").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log('pubmed-form');
    });


  <div id="pubmed-container" style="@(Model.Type == "Pubmed" ? "display:block" : "display:none")">
        <form id="pubmed-form" class="form-horizontal">
            <div id="search-grid-container" style="text-align:center;margin: 20px 0;">
                @(Model.Text)
            </div>
            <hr />

            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary modal-submit-btn">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default modal-close-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Put it in a hidden input or data attribute?

Comment: @rory-mccrossan there only single instance of these fields.

Comment: Is there any other way other then a hidden field?

Comment: You mean something like this data-index='" + @(Model.SortOrder) + "'

Comment: @Jefferson What's your concern with using a hidden input field?

Comment: Not sure how that would work with AJAX

Comment: The same way it would normally, get the form data using `$(yourForm).serialize()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a few ways you could do this, depending on your exact needs. You could add the model property as a `data` attribute on the `form` element which can be read when the `submit` event occurs:

```js
$("#pubmed-form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var sortOrder = $(this).data('sortorder');
  console.log(sortorder);
});
```

```html
<div id="pubmed-container" style="@(Model.Type == "Pubmed" ? "display: block" : "display: none")">
  <form id="pubmed-form" class="form-horizontal" data-sortorder="@Model.SortOrder">
    <div id="search-grid-container">
      @(Model.Text)
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="text-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary modal-submit-btn">Save</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default modal-close-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Alternatively you could use a hidden field, that way you don't need any JS at all, assuming you're not using AJAX:

```
<div id="pubmed-container" style="@(Model.Type == "Pubmed" ? "display: block" : "display: none")">
  <form id="pubmed-form" class="form-horizontal">
    <div id="search-grid-container">
      @(Model.Text)
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="text-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary modal-submit-btn">Save</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default modal-close-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SortOrder)
  </form>
</div>
```

Another way would be to directly output the model value in to the JS, although this arguably binds the JS/C# logic too closely:

```
$("#pubmed-form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var sortOrder = '@Model.SortOrder'; // remove the quotes if the model property is numeric
  console.log(sortorder);
});
```